# asp.net membership custom change of passwords by users and admins

Tags: asp.net, passwords, membership

I am still searching StackOverFlow as well as the innertubes but have not found an example of what I need to do.

1. If an user has forgotten their password and they correctly answer their reminder question, the user is shown two form fields for entering a new password; Not Emailing or displaying a random generated password.
2. If the user calls the support center, an admin can change the password, the reminder question and the answer.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use this code:

```
 var user = Membership.GetUser(username);
 user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), newPassword);
```

this simply first resets the password and then changes it to the new password, you don't need to know the reseted intermediate password

Comment: Okay. The part I am stuck on is that using the Password Recovery wizard, do I use "OnSendingMail" of the PasswordRecovery (to not send email) to display the two input fields for the new password that when submitted calls a method to do what you stated?

Comment: yes using `SendingMail` event you CAN prevent the mail to be sent. this is because `MailMessageEventArgs` (assume `e`) has a property named `Cancel`, you can cancel sending mail by setting `e.Cancel = true;` inside the event handler.

Comment: Correct, I understand that. I am wanting to know if that is where after the user submits their answer and it matches, to call let's say a panel to display the new password form to be submitted.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your question

Comment: What I mean is a situation like this:

1. User goes to the reset page. The reset page is using the Password Recovery control.

2. User goes through the steps of entering username and then entering the answer to the question (that they created when signing up for an account).

3. When the user submits their answer, the Password Recovery control will then cause a panel to be visible if the answer was correct.

I tried using the SendingMail event handler to cancel sending email with code to make a panel visible. This does not happen. I see an error message about needing a "From" email address.

Comment: What I discovered is that even if email will not be sent and using the OnSendingMail method to cancel that, the web.config still requires a From email address section (system.net) entry).